# Security Testing Types

Tags: security, testing

What are the different types of Security Testing?

Comment: i suggest you elaborate on this question to explain what you are looking for. some kind of taxonomy of security testing is pretty subjective and not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

We have a fairly full list which is discussed over on Security Stack Exchange **[here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/nessus-vs-third-party-scans/1623#1623)** and **[here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2837/485)**.

**Discovery**

The purpose of this stage is to identify systems within scope and the services in use. It is not intended to discover vulnerabilities, but version detection may highlight deprecated versions of software / firmware and thus indicate potential vulnerabilities.

**Vulnerability Scan**

Following the discovery stage this looks for known security issues by using automated tools to match conditions with known vulnerabilities. The reported risk level is set automatically by the tool with no manual verification or interpretation by the test vendor. This can be supplemented with credential based scanning that looks to remove some common false positives by using supplied credentials to authenticate with a service (such as local windows accounts).

**Vulnerability Assessment**

This uses discovery and vulnerability scanning to identify security vulnerabilities and places the findings into the context of the environment under test. An example would be removing common false positives from the report and deciding risk levels that should be applied to each report finding to improve business understanding and context.

**Security Assessment**

Builds upon Vulnerability Assessment by adding manual verification to confirm exposure, but does not include the exploitation of vulnerabilities to gain further access. Verification could be in the form of authorised access to a system to confirm system settings and involve examining logs, system responses, error messages, codes, etc. A Security Assessment is looking to gain a broad coverage of the systems under test but not the depth of exposure that a specific vulnerability could lead to.

**Penetration Test**

Penetration testing simulates an attack by a malicious party. Building on the previous stages and involves exploitation of found vulnerabilities to gain further access. Using this approach will result in an understanding of the ability of an attacker to gain access to confidential information, affect data integrity or availability of a service and the respective impact. Each test is approached using a consistent and complete methodology in a way that allows the tester to use their problem solving abilities, the output from a range of tools and their own knowledge of networking and systems to find vulnerabilities that would/ could not be identified by automated tools. This approach looks at the depth of attack as compared to the Security Assessment approach that looks at the broader coverage.

**Security Audit**

Driven by an Audit / Risk function to look at a specific control or compliance issue. Characterised by a narrow scope, this type of engagement could make use of any of the earlier approaches discussed (vulnerability assessment, security assessment, penetration test).

**Security Review**

Verification that industry or internal security standards have been applied to system components or product. This is typically completed through gap analysis and utilises build / code reviews or by reviewing design documents and architecture diagrams. This activity does not utilise any of the earlier approaches (Vulnerability Assessment, Security Assessment, Penetration Test, Security Audit)

Answer (score 2):

- Risk assessment - creating a threat model and defining what will be tested.
- Security auditing - using the threat model to probe the system design.
- Vulnerability scanning - using software to probe the system inplementation.
- Penetration testing - trying to hack into the system, either externally or internally.
- Operational testing - some or all of the above after the system is in production.

Answer (score 1):

- Vulnerability Scanning - Typically an automated procedure to scan one or more systems against known vulnerability signatures.
- Security Scanning - This is a vulnerability scan plus a manual verification of the findings to help remove false positives/ negatives.
  Penetration Testing - A tester will attempt to gain access and prove access to the system owner.
- Risk Assessment - involves a security analysis of interviews with employees compiled with business and industry justifications for risks discovered.
- Security Auditing - Typically an in-depth auditing of software code and/or Operating Systems. This is often a very thorough line-by-line inspection of code.
- Ethical Hacking - This is very similar to a penetration test, but it is usually many of them against a number of systems in order to discover as many attack vectors as possible.
- Posture Assessment and Security Testing - This combines security scanning, ethical hacking and risk assessments to show the overall security posture of the organization.

Each of these security testing types can be further sub-categorized by different methodologies.

Answer (score 0):

Penetration can be of different types, broadly categorized as follows:

- Web parameter tampering: The user manipulates parameters exchanged between client and server and modifies application data such as user credentials, permissions, price or quantity of products, etc. for their benefit.
- Database Tampering: compromising the databases that support the system and store data critical for business or running of the app
- Cookie Stealing: A valid computer session is exploited to gain unauthorized access
- Cross-site Scripting: An attacker injects malicious scripts on the client-side code to redirect the website link.
- Cross-site Request Forgery: Also called one-click attack or session riding, unauthori
- Privilege Escalation: To hack into a senior’s ID and misuse privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s break down security testing into its constituent parts by discussing the different types of security tests that you might perform.

**Static code analysis**
Static code analysis is perhaps the first type of security testing that comes to mind, its the oldest form also. 
Static code analysis involves reviewing source code to identify problems that could lead to security breaches in an application (or in resources to which the application has access). Classic examples of vulnerabilities that you might be looking out for using this type of analysis are coding flaws that could enable buffer overflows or injection attacks.

It’s possible to perform some amount of static code analysis by hand, meaning that developers read through code manually to find security flaws. But that is often not practical to do on a large scale, given the size of many source code files; plus, humans can easily overlook flaws. That’s why using automated analysis tools to scan your source code is important.

**Penetration testing**
Penetration tests involve simulating attacks against an application or infrastructure in order to identify weak points. For example, you could use a tool like nmap to attempt to connect to all endpoints on a network from a non-trusted host and see if any endpoints accept the connection; if they do, you probably want to make them stop accepting connections from arbitrary hosts.

Some folks might argue that penetration testing should be broken down into subcategories, since there are different types of penetration tests. Some focus on the network, some on applications, some on authentication gateways, some on databases, and so on.

**Compliance testing**
Compliance tests (which are sometimes called conformance tests) are used to assess whether a configuration, architecture or process meets an organization’s predefined policies. Compliance testing is not strictly limited to the realm of security; you could conceivably use compliance tests to help maintain standards for application performance or response time, for example.

However, when it comes to security, compliance tests are an important resource for ensuring that a given application’s configuration or deployment architecture meets minimum standards set by your organization. Compliance tests typically work by comparing actual configurations with those that are deemed to be safe. When the tests identify incongruity, admins know that there may be a security issue or other problem.

**Load testing**
Load testing refers to tests that measure how an application or infrastructure performs under heavy demand. Load testing is not often thought of as a type of security test; it’s more commonly used to help optimize application performance and availability.

However, there is a reason why security admins might want to pay attention to load testing results, too. That reason is Distributed-Denial-of-Service, or DDoS, attacks, which aim to disrupt application availability by overwhelming an application or its host infrastructure with traffic or other requests.

**Origin analysis testing**
As the popularity of open source software has grown over the past decade, so has the importance of origin analysis testing. This type of testing helps developers and security admins determine where a given piece of source code originated.

In cases where some of your source code came from a third-party project or repository — which is very common these days, given the ease with which developers can incorporate upstream open source code into their applications — security admins will need to make sure that any known vulnerabilities in that code are addressed, and that the code conforms to internal security standards.